# Facet train layout error with ggmap

Tags: r, rstudio, ggmap

I have a piece of code which has previously worked absolutely fine but for some reason is now giving me error messages.  The code produces various maps using ggmap, here is the most basic first section of that code:

```
map.centre <- c(lon = 35, lat = -2.5)
map <- get_map(location=map.centre, source="google", maptype="satellite", zoom = 8)

ggmap(map, extent= "device")
```

And this is the error its started producing:

```
Error in ggint$train_layout(panel, plot$facet, layer_data, plot$data) : 
  could not find function "facet_train_layout"
In addition: Warning message:
`panel.margin` is deprecated. Please use `panel.spacing` property instead
```

Can anyone explain why my code has worked for months and has now started producing errors and warnings and how I might fix it?  The only thing I can think of is that I've updated R Studio recently but I can't imagine that would have an effect.

Comment: I seem to get the error with every ggmap/ggplot code that I've ever wirtten

Comment: I guess the warning about the deprecated 'panel.margin' comes from ggplot2 because it raised after upgrading to version 2.2.0